# Shopify Online Store 2.0 block not showing on home page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have created a custom section in the Online Store 2.0 Dawn theme and I am trying to get the block to show in the home page, after selecting the image and adding the url, but for some reason it is not showing. Please can some help be provided. Thank you.

Section:

```
<div>
  <h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>

  {% for block in section.blocks %}
    {% case block.type %}

      {% when 'trustBadgesImage' %}
      {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
        <ul>
          {% for block in section.blocks %}
            <li class="trust-badge-section" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              {% if block.settings.trustBadgeslink != blank %}
                <a href="{{ block.settings.trustBadgeslink }}">
                {% endif %}
                {% if block.settings.trustBadgesImage != blank %}
                  {{ block.settings.trustBadgesImage | img_url: '150x150', scale: 2 | img_tag: block.settings.trustBadgesImage.alt, 'trust-badge__image' }}
                {% else %}
                  {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                {% endif %}
                {% if block.settings.trustBadgeslink != blank %}
                </a>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}

    {% endcase %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Trust Badge",
    "tag": "section",
    "class": "trust-badges",
    "max_blocks": 8,
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "trustBadgesTitle",
        "label": "Heading"
      }, {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "trustBadgeslogo_width",
        "label": "Logo width",
        "default": "150px",
        "options": [
          {
            "label": "Extra Small",
            "value": "100px"
          },
          {
            "label": "Small",
            "value": "125px"
          },
          {
            "label": "Medium",
            "value": "150px"
          },
          {
            "label": "Large",
            "value": "175px"
          }, {
            "label": "Extra Large",
            "value": "200px"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "blocks": [
      {
        "name": "Trust Badge Image",
        "type": "trustBadges",
        "settings": [
          {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "trustBadgesImage",
            "label": "Image"
          }, {
            "type": "url",
            "id": "trustBadgeslink",
            "label": "Link",
            "info": "Optional"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

index.json:

```
"trust-badges": {
      "type": "trust-badges",
      "settings": {
        "trustBadgesTitle": "Trust Badge Heading"
        },
        "blocks":{
        "trustBadges": {
          "type": "trustBadges",
          "settings": {
          } 
        }
      },
      "block_order": [
        "trustBadgesTitle",
        "trustBadges"
      ]
    }
},
  "order": [
    "image_banner",
    "trust-badges",
    "rich_text",
    "featured_collection",
    "collage",
    "video",
    "multicolumn"
  ]
```

I tried changing the block.setting to the block id, but this still does not work.

Comment: Is the section added to backend editor, and why adding the section and block directly to index.json. soimply adding a section using code and then use backend editor to add it homepage and made configurations.

Comment: The section is added to the backend editor. Section and block added to index.json as I have followed the same code structure as the section is being added to the Dawn theme. I have also added it to the homepage and made configurations, but still does not show.

Comment: Mostly when you see the section in the backend and choose it to the homepage and made configurations then data into index.json appeared, but I think you add the content to the index.json manually.